# Basic Serial-Communication over Bluetooth (Cmd Syntax Issue?)

Tags: android, serialization, printing, bluetooth, adapter

I'm having trouble communicating with a Avery GSM Indicator (control box w/display for a weigh scale & printer). My inexperience leads me to suspect my command-syntax is way off.

I'm currently establishing a connection with the bluetooth dongle, creating an OutputStream, and attempting to send commands over that with this code:

```
void sendData() throws IOException {
try {
        String msg = txtSend.getText().toString() + "\n"; //txtSend is an EditText element
        mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
        android.util.Log.e(" === ", "Sent [ "+txtSend.getText()+" ]");
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        android.util.Log.e(" === ", "EXCEPTION: Null");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        android.util.Log.e(" === ", "EXCEPTION");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

HARDWARE:

- The weigh-scale and printer are connected on separate serial ports directly into the Indicator-Device.
- The Indicator-Device uses a Serial-to-Bluetooth dongle for wireless communications.
- This Android-App will replace a Windows-CE application (not available) used previously on the same hardware & setup.

DEVICES:

- **Bt Dongle**: http://gridconnect.com/industrial-wireless/bluetooth-serial/serial-to-bluetooth.html
- **Indicator-Device**: (the 650) http://www.averyweigh-tronix.com/service-support/User-Manuals-and-Brochures/#Indicators%20%28W-T%29
- **Indicator-Tech-Ref** (GSE 60 Series): http://www.standardscale.com/PDF/GSE60series_s_en_X60REF.pdf
- **Commands**: http://www.scalemasters.com/650syntax.html

EDIT:

- **May 26th**: This document give some syntax. If this is a full command I'm still lost as to how it is sent. Tried variants of one of the examples, adding %p to print; nothing.

  - `<STX> <ADDRESS> <DATA> <DATA> <DATA> ... <ETX>`
  - page 246, RS-485 NETWORKING : https://www.blackstonescale.com/media/pdf/60SeriesTechRef_Master_3.0.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, it is a command syntax issue.

- Sending only `$` will print some total-sum-value that is internally stored in the 560 indicator device (titled "Total: ").
- Sending `%!` prints a predefined custom-header.
- Judging from my experiments, I don't need any "beginning" or "ending" characters/bytes in the syntax. The firefly adapter must do that for me.

Unfortunately I can not find a reference to these commands anywhere.   'n'

Oh well. Command syntax it is indeed the problem.